# Prove that graph without independent set is not $4$-colorable

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, coloring

Let $G$ be an undirected graph with $n$ vertices so that $n\geq35$ and there isn't an independent set (IS) of size $4$ in $G$.

(If $S$ is a group of vertices from graph $G$, $S$ is an independent set if there isn't an edge in graph $G$ between each two vertices from $S$)

Prove that $G$ isn't $4$-colorable.

There was a clue in addition to the question that implied the use of Ramsey Theory, specifically the upper bound on Ramsey Numbers. Is there a way to prove it using Ramsey Theory?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assume there is a 4-coloration of $G$, then there must be a set $S$ of vertices of same color of size at least $\lceil 35/4\rceil=9$. But since $S$ cannot be an independent set, there is an edge between two vertices of $S$, which contradicts the fact that they are of same color.

**EDIT: alternative proof using Ramsey Theory**

Ramsey theory gives us the existence of big cliques or big independent sets if the graph is big enough. Here we know that there is no big independent set, so by Ramsey there must be a big clique, which prevents small colorations. To show that it's not $4$-coloriable, we would need a $5$-clique, so the relevant Ramsey number is $R(4,5)=25$ (check [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramsey_number#Ramsey_numbers)). Since $35\geq 25$ and we know that there is no $4$-independent set, such a $5$-clique is guaranteed to exist. But this proof is unnecessarily complicated...

Comment: Great answer! got it!
I forgot to point out that there was a clue in addition to the question that implied the use of Ramsey Theory, specifically the upper bound on Ramsey Numbers. Is there a way to prove it using Ramsey Theory?

Comment: Ramsey theory gives us the existence of big cliques or big independent sets if the graph is big enough. Here we know that there is no big independent set, so by Ramsey there must be a big clique, which prevents small colorations. To show that it's not 4-coloriable, we would need a 5-clique, so the relevant Ramsey number is R(4,5)=25 (check wikipedia). Since 35>=25 and we know that there is no 4-independent set, such a 5-clique is guaranteed to exist. But this proof is unnecessary complicated...

Comment: I added it in the answer, since this might be what you were looking for.

Comment: O.k, but aren't Ramsey is only about Complete Graphs (Kn) ?

Comment: on wikipedia it is stated with two colors blue and red, but it is equivalent to considering that blue is "egde" and red is "no edge". Then a blue-colored set is a clique and a red-colored set is an IS.

Comment: Ok, got it! Thanks!!