# If $G$ is a graph with no independent set of size $4$, prove that it is not $4$ colorable

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

> Given $G$ a graph with $n \geq {7 \choose 3} = 35$ vertices, and with no independent sets of size $4$, prove it is ***not*** $4$ colorable. (independent set of vertices is a set of vertices that has no edges between any two of the vertices)

This was in the exam I did today.

This was my answer and my professor tells me it is probably wrong (after I asked him personally):

> Assume it is $4$ colorable, and since we have at least $35$ vertices, we take the $4$ colours as cages and the $n \geq 35$ vertices as pigeons, so according to the pigeonhole principle there is a cage with at least $4$ vertices. If it has $4$, you take them, and they are of the same colour then according to the rules of colouring it is an independent set of $4$ vertices. If it has more than $(k > 4)$, then you take $4$ out of these $k$ vertices, and again, they should be independent set of size $4$. In contradiction to the given info that the graph has no independent set of size $4$.

What exactly is wrong about that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There’s nothing wrong with it, though you could have drawn a stronger conclusion from the pigeonhole principle: with $35$ vertices and $4$ colors, there must be at least $9$ vertices of one color, so there must be an independent set of at least $9$ vertices, hence certainly one of $4$. Someone else [asked about this problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/434439/prove-that-graph-without-independent-set-is-not-4-colorable/434445#434445) recently and specifically asked about a proof using Ramsey theory; the answer given there covers that (unnecessarily complicated) argument as well.

Comment: Yes I saw it just now, but still nothing wrong with my assumption. And yes, one of my friends told me he solved it with Ramsey, and given that my professor said it is wrong (as a first glance) I thought I was going to fail this course.

Thank you!

Comment: @TheNotMe: You’re welcome!